# Why this error when I try to execute my Docker containers? bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am starting following a course on Udemy. This couse uses Docker and I am finding the following problem. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as operating system.

I have this **docker-compose.yml** file (provided as course resource):

```
version: '3.3'

networks: 
  ntpgsql:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/24

services:
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes: 
      - psdb-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: 
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.2
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5433 
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123_Stella
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: pgadmin4
    
    networks:
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.3
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=True
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=may-email@gmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=123_Stella


volumes:
  psdb-volume:
```

So I accessed to the directory containing this configuration file and from my shell I performed this command to download and start rthese two containers defined into my configuration file:

```
docker-compose up
```

Images seems to be correctly downloaded but, at the end, I obtain this error message when it try to start the containers:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for dpage/pgadmin4:latest
Creating pgadmin4 ... 
Creating pgadmin4   ... error
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

ERROR: for pgadmin4  Cannot start service pgadmin: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pgadmin4 (a1643d333555ed47a666d5df57ab5db20a1f5e0a141fe6026f135689b1b7541d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8Creating postgresql ... done

ERROR: for pgadmin  Cannot start service pgadmin: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pgadmin4 (a1643d333555ed47a666d5df57ab5db20a1f5e0a141fe6026f135689b1b7541d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
andrea@ubuntu:~/Documents/spirng-microservies-course$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
8467ee204a9d   postgres:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp, :::5433->5432/tcp   postgresql
```

It seems to me that it have correctly started the first container listed in my configuration file (the one named **postgresql**) but not the second one (named **pgadmin4**).

What could be the problem? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: The port may be in use by a stopped container. Try `docker ps -a` to see stopped containers. Then remove the ones you don't need using `docker rm <container name>`

Comment: An Apache or Nginx server running on your host, not in a container, could also cause this.  The easiest workaround is to change the `ports: [{ published: }]` value, but the linked question also has some suggestions on finding the host process with the port.

Comment: (P.S.: the `docker-compose.yml` file could be dramatically shorter.  You should be able to delete all of the `networks:` blocks; Compose will create a network named `default` for you and automatically assign IP addresses.  You don't need to set `container_name:`, and there's a much shorter `ports: ['5433:5432']` syntax.)